# ReferenceError: safari is not defined

Tags: safari, referenceerror, defined

Whenever I click on a textarea the following message pops up:

[image]

What could possibly trigger this?

Thanks!
Note: I'm using JQM 1.4.5 and the textarea is normal, nothing was configured.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on one of my projects, with the same traceback as yours.  It was strange, as there was no bundle.js in my project, or even being loaded.  I found it was an issue with one of my extensions, so disabling extensions and clearing cache should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using chrome browser?
2. If so, sign out of your chrome browser. That should fix it.
   It might be that you have some installed chrome extensions whose javascript codes are conflicting with your project